# Running Miniconda3 on Chromebook Linux Beta

Tags: linux, anaconda, chromebook

[image]

I am having some trouble setting up miniconda3 on my chromebook, I have tried reopening as stated but all I get is `conda: command not found`, Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It tells you to restart your shell. I don't think you have ...

Comment: Hi, DavidPostill thank you for your response!! It turns out I just had to activate it by cd (PATH)/bin and then source activate root

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, the conda initialization is setup for `root` user in `/root/.bashrc` not not current user.

The problem should be fixed by executing `conda init` without `sudo` to setup the init for current user.